Help assessing Toyota RAV4 2003 undercarriage corrosion
I am considering buying a Toyota RAV4 2003 for around 2000 GBP and saw this underneath.
Can someone help me identify what the slightly strange looking pipe on the left is and tell me if anything looks problematic about it or anything else they can see in the photo?
Any help would be incredibly appreciated since I know virtually nothing about cars.

I'm not an expert, but the rusty pipe is 98% the exhaust pipe. To check it you can follow it from the read end. Anyway it shows "usual UK rust"

If you're referring to the pipe that's left of center, almost in line with the left front tire, that's the exhaust pipe. I can see slight surface corrosion along the main pipe that looks like acne but is otherwise unremarkable. There is some discoloration at the welds on the flanges connecting the two pieces of exhaust together (the bolted section). That's also nothing special.
I live in a location where we use salt on the roads in the winter and we certainly get a lot more rust on our vehicles than this one is showing!
